# Encoding custom python objects as BSON with pymongo

Tags: python, numpy, pymongo, bson

Is there a way to tell pymongo to use a custom encoder to convert python objects to BSON?

Specifically I need to convert numpy arrays into BSON.  I know I can manually ensure every numpy array gets converted to a native python array before sending it to pymongo.  But this is repetitive and error-prone.  I'd much rather have a way to set up my pymongo connection to do this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a `SONManipulator`.  From the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/custom_type.html#automatic-encoding-and-decoding):

SONManipulator instances allow you to specify transformations to be applied automatically by PyMongo.

```
from pymongo.son_manipulator import SONManipulator

class Transform(SONManipulator):
  def transform_incoming(self, son, collection):
    for (key, value) in son.items():
      if isinstance(value, Custom):
        son[key] = encode_custom(value)
      elif isinstance(value, dict): # Make sure we recurse into sub-docs
        son[key] = self.transform_incoming(value, collection)
    return son
  def transform_outgoing(self, son, collection):
    for (key, value) in son.items():
      if isinstance(value, dict):
        if "_type" in value and value["_type"] == "custom":
          son[key] = decode_custom(value)
        else: # Again, make sure to recurse into sub-docs
          son[key] = self.transform_outgoing(value, collection)
    return son
```

then add it to your pymongo database object:

```
db.add_son_manipulator(Transform())
```

Note you don't have to add the `_type` field if you want to silently cast a numpy array to a python array.

Comment: `son_manipulator` is currently deprecated. They'll be removed on v4.0. The official recomendation is to transform documents before passing them to pymongo, as stated in the [docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/son_manipulator.html)